# Struts2 how to get an ActionError count in a jsp

Tags: javascript, struts2, jsp-tags

In Struts2 I have successfully implemented an `updateErrorCount()` method that updates a class member variable every time `addActionError()` is called through out various action classes. I can then access that variable with a property tag in the associated `jsp`.  However, I am looking for a better solution. 
Since the `s:actionerror` tag lists all of the errors added, is there a way to use an iterator tag or some other solution to display the error count along with all of the error messages right in the `jsp`?

I thought about overriding `addActionError()` to avoid having to call an additional method to keep an error count but if I could simply do it all in the `jsp` it seems much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

[`getActionErrors` returns a collection](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getActionErrors()), why can't you just call `size` on that?

I see few legitimate reasons to implement any of this functionality manually.

If you have specific needs you should enumerate them in your question, otherwise I don't see the point of doing this on your own.